# How to Update json.stringify on keystroke with onChange handler in react

Tags: json, reactjs, react-hooks

I am currently working on a react project. I have a nested object. E.g.

```js
const tree = {
  name: "root",
  chidren: [
    {
      name: "child1",
      data: "hello-world"
    }
  ]
}
```

How can I update its value in real-time while typing.
Example output with `JSON.stringify(tree)`:
`{"name":"child-alan","data":"hi-world"}`.

How do I go about this? Any answer will be really appreciated.

Comment: You want to update the object, correct? Not JSON.stringify, which is a built-in method that nobody sane really wants to change?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to edit a specific child, like that one child, define a state for the data, then use a `input` to edit it with `onChange` which updates the data upon change. Make it a controlled input.

After that, you can stringify it, or do whatever you need with it.

```
const tree = {
    name:"root",
    children: [
            { 
             name: "child1",
             data: "hello-world"
           }
     ]
    
  }
  //State to store the values, set them as initial.
  const [treeData, setTreeData] = useState(tree.children[0])

  
  
  function handleChange(event){
    setTreeData({...treeData, [event.target.name]:event.target.value})
  }

 

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h2>Edit the tree children</h2>
       <input type="text" name="name" value={treeData.name} onChange={handleChange} />
    </div>
  );
```

[image: Example with the input shown.]

[image: Console log of the changes]

---

IF you want to add a new item instead to the children array, and then you can stringify when you need to. If I misunderstood your question, please elaborate, and I will try to help you out.

```
 //State to store the values, set them as initial.
  const [child, setChild] = useState({ name: "", data: "" });

  function handleChange(event) {
    setChild({ ...child, [event.target.name]: event.target.value });
  }

  function onSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    tree.children.push(child);
    setChild({ name: "", data: "" });
    console.log(tree);
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h2>Edit the tree children</h2>
      <form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
        <input
          type="text"
          name="name"
          value={child.name}
          onChange={handleChange}
        />
        <button type="submit">SUBMIT</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
```

[image: Adding to the array extra children]